# Issue with an array of MediaPlayer objects

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that uses the MediaPlayer class to make sound files into playable files that Android handles easier.
All the inefficient code is due to the fact that we are only allowed to use the resources that have been taught so far.
Right now, I am having a problem with an array of the MediaPlayer objects.

We are instructed to make a button that makes Twinkle Twinkle Little Star play.
Anytime an object (mpA, mpB, etc.) is called, the sound plays.
However whenever the object is called with the array (mediaFiles[0], mediaFiles[1], etc.), the app crashes due to a `NullPointerExeption`.

The object is not null, and I have tested this multiple times.
The object is being seen as a MediaPlayer object.

Both me and my teacher have no idea what could be causing this.

```
package com.example.mgeyer.synthesizer;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

public class SynthesizerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int WHOLE_NOTE = 1000;
    private static final String TAG =
            SynthesizerActivity.class.getName();
    private Button mAButton;
    private Button mASButton;
    private Button mBButton;
    private Button mCButton;
    private Button mCSButton;
    private Button mDButton;
    private Button mDSButton;
    private Button mEButton;
    private Button mFButton;
    private Button mFSButton;
    private Button mGButton;
    private Button mGSButton;
    private Button mHEButton;
    private Button mHFButton;
    private Button mHFSButton;
    private Button mHGButton;
    private MediaPlayer mpA;
    private MediaPlayer mpAS;
    private MediaPlayer mpB;
    private MediaPlayer mpC;
    private MediaPlayer mpCS;
    private MediaPlayer mpD;
    private MediaPlayer mpDS;
    private MediaPlayer mpE;
    private MediaPlayer mpF;
    private MediaPlayer mpFS;
    private MediaPlayer mpG;
    private MediaPlayer mpGS;
    private MediaPlayer mpHE;
    private MediaPlayer mpHF;
    private MediaPlayer mpHFS;
    private MediaPlayer mpHG;
    private NumberPicker numberPickerNote;
    private NumberPicker numberPickerAmount;
   // private int timesPlayed = 1;
    //private MediaPlayer selectedNote = mpA;
    private MediaPlayer[] mediaFiles = {mpA, mpAS, mpB, mpC, mpCS, mpD, mpDS, mpE, mpF, mpFS, mpG, mpGS, mpHE, mpHF, mpHFS, mpHG};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_synthesizer);
        mAButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aButton);
        mASButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.asButton);
        mBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bButton);
        mCButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cButton);
        mCSButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.csButton);
        mDButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dButton);
        mDSButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dsButton);
        mEButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eButton);
        mFButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fButton);
        mFSButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fsButton);
        mGButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gButton);
        mGSButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gsButton);
        mHEButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.heButton);
        mHFButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hfButton);
        mHFSButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hfsButton);
        mHGButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hgButton);
        mpA = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalea);
        mpAS = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scaleas);
        mpB = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scaleb);
        mpC = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalec);
        mpCS = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalecs);
        mpD = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scaled);
        mpDS = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scaleds);
        mpE = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalee);
        mpF = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalef);
        mpFS = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalefs);
        mpG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scaleg);
        mpGS = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalegs);
        mpHE = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalehighe);
        mpHF = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalehighf);
        mpHFS = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalehighfs);
        mpHG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalehighg);
        numberPickerNote = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        numberPickerAmount = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
        numberPickerNote.setMinValue(1);
        numberPickerNote.setMaxValue(16);
        numberPickerAmount.setMinValue(1);
        numberPickerAmount.setMaxValue(10);

        numberPickerNote.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                //selectedNote = mediaFiles[numberPickerNote.getValue() - 1];
            }
        });

        numberPickerAmount.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                //timesPlayed = numberPickerAmount.getValue();
            }
        });
    }

    private void delayPlaying(int delay) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("SynthesizerActivity", "Audio playback interrupted");
        }
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        mpA.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "A Button clicked");
        mpA.start();
    }

    public void onButton2Click(View v) {
        mpAS.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "A# Button clicked");
        mpAS.start();
    }

    public void onButton3Click(View v) {
        mpB.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "B Button clicked");
        mpB.start();
    }

    public void onButton4Click(View v) {
        mpC.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "C Button clicked");
        mpC.start();
    }

    public void onButton5Click(View v) {
        mpCS.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "C# Button clicked");
        mpCS.start();
    }

    public void onButton6Click(View v) {
        mpD.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "D Button clicked");
        mpD.start();
    }

    public void onButton7Click(View v) {
        mpDS.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "D# Button clicked");
        mpDS.start();
    }

    public void onButton8Click(View v) {
        mpE.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "E Button clicked");
        mpE.start();
    }

    public void onButton9Click(View v) {
        mpF.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "F Button clicked");
        mpF.start();
    }

    public void onButton10Click(View v) {
        mpFS.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "F# Button clicked");
        mpFS.start();
    }

    public void onButton11Click(View v) {
        mpG.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "G Button clicked");
        mpG.start();
    }

    public void onButton12Click(View v) {
        mpGS.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "G# Button clicked");
        mpGS.start();
    }

    public void onButton13Click(View v) {
        mpHE.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "High E Button clicked");
        mpHE.start();
    }

    public void onButton14Click(View v) {
        mpHF.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "High F Button clicked");
        mpHF.start();
    }

    public void onButton15Click(View v) {
        mpHFS.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "High F# Button clicked");
        mpHFS.start();
    }

    public void onButton16Click(View v) {
        mpHG.seekTo(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "High G Button clicked");
        mpHG.start();
    }

    public void onButton17Click(View v) {
        try {
            mpE.seekTo(0);
            mpE.start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE/2);
            mpFS.seekTo(0);
            mpFS.start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE/2);
            mpG.seekTo(0);
            mpG.start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE/2);
            mpA.seekTo(0);
            mpA.start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE/2);
            mpB.seekTo(0);
            mpB.start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE/2);
            mpCS.seekTo(0);
            mpCS.start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE/2);
            mpD.seekTo(0);
            mpD.start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE/2);
            mpHE.seekTo(0);
            mpHE.start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE/2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onSelectedNoteClick(View v) {
        for (int i = numberPickerAmount.getValue(); i > 0; i--) {
            try {
                mediaFiles[(numberPickerNote.getValue() - 1)].seekTo(0);
                mediaFiles[(numberPickerNote.getValue() - 1)].start();
                delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTwinkleClick (View v) {
        try {
            mediaFiles[0].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[0].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[0].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[0].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[13].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[13].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[13].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[13].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 2);
            mediaFiles[5].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[5].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[5].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[5].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[4].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[4].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[4].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[4].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[2].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[2].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[2].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[2].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[0].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[0].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 2);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[5].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[5].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[5].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[5].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[4].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[4].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[4].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[4].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[2].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[2].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 2);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[5].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[5].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[5].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[5].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[4].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[4].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[4].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[4].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[2].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[2].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 2);
            mediaFiles[0].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[0].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[0].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[0].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[13].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[13].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[13].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[13].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[12].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[12].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 2);
            mediaFiles[5].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[5].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[5].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[5].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[4].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[4].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[4].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[4].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[2].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[2].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[2].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[2].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 4);
            mediaFiles[0].seekTo(0);
            mediaFiles[0].start();
            delayPlaying(WHOLE_NOTE / 2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is the output of the debugger.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.mgeyer.synthesizer, PID: 4066
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.seekTo(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.mgeyer.synthesizer.SynthesizerActivity.onTwinkleClick(SynthesizerActivity.java:261)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Why do you create so many media player objects? Is the app supposed to play several files at the same time?

Comment: Also the rest of the code is really redundant, one onButtonClick method is totally sufficient because you know from the view paramter which button has been clicked on.

Comment: Please see about a [mcve]. Keyword being minimal.

Answer (score 1):

If you test this with a much simpler example, you will see that the values are indeed null in this case.

e.g. with

```
   public class Test
  {
   Object o1; //reference to null! (default value)
   Object [] tests = new Object[] {o1}; //..therefore tests contains null


  public void test()
  {
    this.o1=new Object(); //now points to a new object, but tests[0]...
    System.out.println(this.tests[0]); //...has the null reference
    System.out.println(this.o1); //prints out reference to object
    this.tests[0]=this.o1; //now tests[0] points to the same object...
    System.out.println(this.tests[0]); //...as this.o1

  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Test().test();
  }
}
```

Always remember that you only put a *reference* (i.e. pointer) to an object (or null) in the array. If the attribute points to a new object (in your case a MediaPlayer object) this will *not* change the original reference, which has the same address as before.

A real-world example would be an address book containing a friend's address. If this friend moves, the entry in your address book will still point to his/her old home.

Edit: You don't need that many implementations of the onButtonClick method, one is sufficient since you have the view parameter which tells you which button was clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

> The object is not null, and I have tested this multiple times. The object is being seen as a MediaPlayer object

The object is null. The stacktrace doesn't lie...

> Both me and my teacher have no idea what could be causing this

Does your teacher know Java?

Making an array of your fields that are not initialized will definitely make them null!

---

Instead of this ...

```
private MediaPlayer[] mediaFiles = {mpA, mpAS, mpB, mpC, mpCS, mpD, mpDS, mpE, mpF, mpFS, mpG, mpGS, mpHE, mpHF, mpHFS, mpHG};
```

Replace with this

```
private MediaPlayer[] mediaFiles;
```

And **within `onCreate`**, you can create that array with the non-null references.

```
// Other players...
mpHG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalehighg);
mediaFiles = {mpA, mpAS, mpB, mpC, mpCS, mpD, mpDS, mpE, mpF, mpFS, mpG, mpGS, mpHE, mpHF, mpHFS, mpHG};
```

---

Or use a `HashMap<Integer, MediaPlayer>` like so

```
private Map<Integer, MediaPlayer> mediaPlayerMap = new HashMap<Integer, MediaPlayer>();

...

// For example
button.setTag(R.raw.scalehighg);
mediaPlayerMap.put(R.raw.scalehighg,  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scalehighg));

...

// Any button click...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Integer songId = (Integer) v.getTag();
    MediaPlayer mp = mediaPlayerMap.get(songId);
    mp.seekTo(0);
    mp.start();
}
```

Though, realistically, I think you only need one `MediaPlayer` depending on your needs.